# Add key / value to XML file

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<confluence-configuration>
  <setupStep>complete</setupStep>
  <setupType>custom</setupType>
  <buildNumber>8506</buildNumber>
  <properties>
    <property name="attachments.dir">${confluenceHome}/attachments</property>
    <property name="confluence.setup.server.id">BN4J-RBSE-6ZPZ-GB4G</property>
    <property name="confluence.webapp.context.path"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/confluence</property>
    <property name="hibernate.database.lower_non_ascii_supported">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">com.atlassian.confluence.impl.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.setup">true</property>
    <property name="lucene.index.dir">${localHome}/index</property>
    <property name="synchrony.encryption.disabled">true</property>
    <property name="synchrony.proxy.enabled">true</property>
    <property name="webwork.multipart.saveDir">${localHome}/temp</property>
  </properties>
</confluence-configuration>
```

What is the best method to add key / value pairs like shown below?

```
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">60</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">30</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
```

I'm hoping to do so with xmlstarlet.

EDIT 1:
I tried:

```
xmlstarlet edit --update "/confluence-configuration/properties/property[@name='hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment']/@name" --value "1" confluence.cfg.xml
```

But that messes my xml file up

EDIT 2: apparently that had to do with
`<property name="confluence.webapp.context.path"></property>`
I have now a working update command:

```
xmlstarlet ed --update "/confluence-configuration/properties/property[@name='hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment']" --value "5" confluence.cfg.xml
```

But how about inserting?

Thank you!

Comment: Try this:`xmlstarlet edit -L --subnode "/confluence-configuration/properties" --type elem -n property --value "1" --insert "/confluence-configuration/properties/property[last()]" --type attr -n name --value "hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" confluence.cfg.xml`

Comment: Thank you Rob. How can i prevent it from adding duplicate lines?

Comment: `<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</property>`

Comment: Not sure I understand your last comment? What is adding duplicate lines?

Comment: If i run your command multiple times, it adds multiple lines as well. Should i combine it with an if clause to check if it exists first? Say; `if [ -n "$(xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v "/confluence-configuration/properties/property[@name='hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment']/@name" confluence.cfg.xml)" ];`

Comment: Yes of course, running the command that I provided in my first comment multiple times will result in multiple lines being inserted (a new line for each time the command is run!). So, again I'm not sure what you mean. Perhaps your queston may be clearer if you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68082904/edit) it to show what you want the contents of the resultant xml file to be.

Comment: Hi Rob, understood. The "problem" is that this file might already exist, but the contents can differ from server to server - so i have to prepare for either settings being there already - and in that case update them - or not and add them. But i think i can manage that with your command + my update command (see edit) within a if/else statement :)

Comment: Yes, `if/else` branching would be the way to go then. It's worth noting that xmlstarlet has the `-Q` (quiet) option, so I can't see a need for command substitution (i.e. `$(...)`) in your `if` condition. You can do just the following to check if the node and attribute already exists instead:  `if xmlstarlet sel -Q -t -v "/confluence-configuration/properties/property[@name='hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment']" confluence.cfg.xml; then`

Comment: Thanks for your help RobC, i posted my own answer just now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the nicest way but i resolved it like this;

```
declare -A xmlArray
  xmlArray[hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment]=1
  xmlArray[hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period]=100
  xmlArray[hibernate.c3p0.max_size]=${CONFLUENCE_MAX_DB_CONNECTIONS}
  xmlArray[hibernate.c3p0.max_statements]=0
  xmlArray[hibernate.c3p0.min_size]=20
  xmlArray[hibernate.c3p0.timeout]=30
  xmlArray[hibernate.c3p0.validate]=true
  xmlArray[hibernate.connection.driver_class]=org.postgresql.Driver
  xmlArray[hibernate.connection.isolation]=2
  xmlArray[hibernate.connection.password]=${CONFLUENCE_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
  xmlArray[hibernate.connection.url]=${CONFLUENCE_DATABASE_URL}
  xmlArray[hibernate.connection.username]=${CONFLUENCE_DATABASE_USERNAME}

  xmlstarlet ed --inplace -d "/confluence-configuration/properties/property[@name='hibernate.connection.datasource']" ${CONFLUENCE_HOME}/confluence.cfg.xml

  for KEY in "${!xmlArray[@]}"; do
    if [ -n "$(xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v "/confluence-configuration/properties/property[@name='$KEY']/@name" ${CONFLUENCE_HOME}/confluence.cfg.xml)" ]; then
      xmlstarlet ed --inplace --update "/confluence-configuration/properties/property[@name='$KEY']" --value "${xmlArray[$KEY]}" ${CONFLUENCE_HOME}/confluence.cfg.xml;
    else
      xmlstarlet edit -L --subnode "/confluence-configuration/properties" --type elem -n property --value "${xmlArray[$KEY]}" --insert "/confluence-configuration/properties/property[last()]" --type attr -n name --value "$KEY" ${CONFLUENCE_HOME}/confluence.cfg.xml;
    fi
  done
```